# Explain the behavior of "undelete" option of deleted questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, superuser

I have a deleted question,

https://superuser.com/questions/545709/how-to-disable-solid-colours-page-from-windows-10s-wallpaper-personalization

I really would like to undelete that question, however, I don't understand at all the logic or behavior in which is based the opportunities that I have to.

I have much doubts about this.

- If a question is deleted or in other words isn't visible for users, then who will vote to undelete that question since it's not visible/accessible to common users?
- When I make use of my vote to undelete, is some kind of "signal" emitted to moderators or other privileged users in form of an advise/popup about a user wanting to undelete a question?
- (Same as question number 2, but in other words) Do moderators have advises of undeletes and they revise undelete requests? Will moderators at least know that a user has requested an undelete?
- If a question is deleted, is it allowed to publish a new question with the same (fixed) content? That is, what I should do?.
- Additionally and optionally: How does the "undelete" feature work in general?

Comment: You should be asking one question per question, rather than 8 questions in a question.

Comment: @Servy If an user does that then that will be a redundant conduct, redundancy is not good approved on StackExchange communities. I personaly really think there is any problem to ask some questions which in essence are the same and are related to the same issue, instead of publishing 8 posts talking about the same problem but throwing the "same" question with little differences. thanks for comment!

Comment: You didn't just post the rephrased question 8 times.  They are actually different questions.  If they were all the same question then I'd just say that you should remove all but one of them.

Comment: @Servy I removed 3 questions wich was poor well-constructed. But I think that I'm in the right reasoning if I think that meta is intended to help users of the community instead of being very restrictive about "make 1 queston for each post" as the other comunities because meta has a different behavior, anyways, a moderator/person who knows how the "undelete" works in general then it could resolve/answer to my doubts in few words, Ill mean that I'm not asking questions in which an answer to each of them could fill an entire page, are short questions that surely needs short answers...

Comment: Asking one question per question isn't unique to Meta; it's important to all meta and non-meta sites.  Limiting questions to just one question is *how* the site ensures that questions better help people, as it makes the individual points much easier to discuss, improves clarity, ensures proper scoping of posts, improves searchability of content, etc.  And if you think all of these questions are very short, in particular the last point, then you're simply mistaken.  "Tell me everything about X?" is a textbook too broad question.  The rest aren't individually too broad.

Comment: @Servy about the last question I only was looking for any kind of info in a general way, short or large, just any thing that help me to udnerstand. Anyways I think you have reason in what you said, I will try to keep your suggestions in mind. thanks for comment again and sorry for my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a question is deleted or in other words isn't visible for users, then who will vote to undelete that question since its not visible/accessible to common users?.

Anyone who has at least 10,000 reputation on Super User will be able to see deleted questions, and can vote to undelete them if they so wish, as long as the question hasn't been locked through deletion by either an elected mod (a user with a diamond next to their name), or the Community User.

> When I make use of my vote to undelete, some kind of "signal" is emmited to moderators or other privileged users in form of an advise/popup about an user wants to undelete a question?.
>
> (same as question nº2 but in other words) Moderators has advises of undeletes and they revises undelete requests?. At least moderators will know that an user has requested an undelete?.

I'm not 100% sure what happens when you try to undelete your own question. If you deleted it yourself, I think you might be able to just undelete it yourself (not sure though).

If other non-mod users voted to delete your question, and it was deleted, then it will take 3 undelete votes or a single undelete vote from a mod to undelete your question. Undelete votes can be seen globally across the entire site by users with at least 10,000 reputation, so if someone casts an undelete vote on a question, then these users will know about it.

However, once again, if the question was deleted by an elected mod or the Community User, then the question is "locked", and can only be undeleted by a mod.

> An user really could have hope/chance to see his deleted question undeleted?.

If the community thinks that your question has value, then yes, it has a chance of being undeleted. Otherwise, no.

> If a question is deleted, it is allowed to publish a new question with the same (fixed) content?. that is what I should do?.

There's a reason your question was deleted. It probably did not meet the standards of the Super User community. Posting the exact same question again probably isn't going to do you any good. If you think you can post a *new* version of the question that would meet community standards, then you could probably try that with better results.

If your question was completely off-topic for the site to begin with, however, then you shouldn't repost it if any version of the question that you could come up with would still be off-topic.

> It is allowed to use the chat to "spam" requesting for an undelete of a question?. Is there a place on S.E. to request this, more than the usage of the "undelete" button?.

## NO

I don't see how "spamming" anything in any venue here would be welcome, by anyone. You could probably ask very politely *once* if users want to undelete your question, but you should be prepared for a polite but firm No, *in the best case*.

> Why some deleted questions has an additional "reopen" option while other questions only have the "undelete" option?.

Questions that have a status of "On Hold" or "Closed" can no longer be answered. Once they have one of those statuses, users can vote to re-open them for answering if the questions meet community standards, such as through editing, for example.

This is different from deletion. A question can be closed, but can remain on the site until a mod or a group of users votes to delete it. Once a question is deleted, it cannot be reopened until it is undeleted first.

Comment: Thank for answer. Now I feel sorry for the lot of questions I did, but you helped me to understand it in a better way. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @bob "it will take 3 undelete votes or a single undelete vote from a mod to undelete your question." - or, I believe, a single vote from a gold badge holder for one of the question tags.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm pretty sure that only applies to closing and re-opening questions duplicate questions, not deleting and un-deleting them...I'll need to double check on that (the "dupe hammer", as people like to call it).

Comment: @bob I checked, you're correct, my mistake.